# How do I edit video with blender

Tags: video-sequence-editor, edit-mode, video

I have never edited a video in the VSE. What is the least necessary to set up for editing in the VSE? I already have 3 mp4s in the VSE but dont know where to go from here?

I am trying to make one video from 3 parts.

Comment: This question is off topic, since it asks for a tutorial to a very broad topic.

Answer (score 1):

All you have to do is drag and drop each clip so they are right after each other in the correct order. Then make sure the length of your animation is the same as the length of the 3 clips (you can set the frames in the render tab of the properties panel). Finally, select your output format (output panel of the render tab) and render the animation. If you have nothing else in your scene it should render very quickly. If you have anything else in your scene, the VSE will override everything in your scene and the final animation will be only what is in the VSE.

Comment: Thank you Brenticus. It didn't work so I'll have to start another question.